# UITableViewDiffableDataSource set different cell animations

Tags: swift, uitableview, diffabledatasource

I'm using `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` to render cells, and I wonder how to animate rows granularily.

There's a property

```
self.dataSource?.defaultRowAnimation = .fade
```

which apply for all rows of the tableView, but I would like some animation for certain cells, and NO animation for others. The "default" in "defaultRowAnimation" suggest there are other methods.

Unfortunately, Apple documentation on the subjet is [a bit light](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdiffabledatasource)

Is there a method that asks a `RowAnimation` according to the given `IndexPath` for example?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution.

Comment: @Martin could you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a delegate method or similar that asks you which animation to use for which cell, however in `UITableViewDiffableDataSource.update(sections:)` you can choose which animation to use based on any criteria you like as long as its represented in the model. E.g.

```swift
class MyTableViewDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<ListSectionID, ListItemID> {

func update(animated: Bool = true) {
    var newSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<ListSectionID, ListItemID>()
    newSnapshot.appendSections([.theSection])

    if let items = DataManager.shared.itemsUsingFadeAnimation {
        let ids = items.map { ListItemID(id: $0.id) }
        newSnapshot.appendItems(items, toSection: .theSection)
        .defaultRowAnimation = .fade
        apply(newSnapshot, animatingDifferences: animated)
    }
    if let items = DataManager.shared.itemsUsingMiddleAnimation {
        let ids = items.map { ListItemID(id: $0.id) }
        // insert these ids into the snapshot using `appendItems` or `insertItems`
        .defaultRowAnimation = .middle
        apply(newSnapshot, animatingDifferences: animated)
    }

}
```